# How jailbreakme manages to install an iphone / ipad app from its website without using app store?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Since the ipad or iphone isn't yet jailbreaked how can an app install outside app store ?!!! or was I mistaken that app store was the only way if your device wasn't jailbreaked.

Comment: Via a security hole in the iphone operating system.

Comment: Specifically, in its PDF parser.

Comment: It exploits a font handling library that the PDF parser uses.

Comment: I love how innocent sounding "font handling library" sounds :)

Comment: Anyway, it's fixed in 4.3.4 sonif your planning on exploiting it, then tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched the console as I jailbroke a device and it is exploiting an issue with the way fonts are handled with the pdf parser. [Sogeti ESEC Lab](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/post/Analysis-of-the-jailbreakme-v3-font-exploit) has written a detailed analysis of how this done.

Comment: I think their analysis is accurate. Especially as comex (one of the developers that worked on Spirit, JBme 2.0 and this current JBme 3.0 jailbreak itself) tweeted a link to the article.